# Strange questions about elasticsearch java api error

Tags: java, scala, maven, elasticsearch

I want to use spark-streaming to get kafka datas and write to Es. I use the 5.4 java API. My environment is spark_2.1.1 (standalone), kafka is 0.10.0.1, es is 5.4.1. I can get kafka data correctly. But when i try to write data to Es, it show some errors:

> WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, xxx): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.util.internal.ObjectUtil.checkPositive(ILjava/lang/String;)I
>       at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime$AvailableProcessorsHolder.setAvailableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:44)
>       at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime$AvailableProcessorsHolder.availableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:70)
>       at io.netty.util.NettyRuntime.availableProcessors(NettyRuntime.java:98)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.setAvailableProcessors(Netty4Utils.java:83)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.(Netty4Transport.java:138)
>       at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:65)
>       at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security.lambda$getTransports$13(Security.java:779)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:176)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.(TransportClient.java:268)
>       at org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient.(PreBuiltTransportClient.java:127)
>       at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:55)
>       at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:50)
>       at org.elasticsearch.xpack.client.PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.(PreBuiltXPackTransportClient.java:46)

But I find I have this method，like that：
`Maven:io.netty:netty-all:4.1.11.Final and Maven:io.netty:netty-common:4.1.11.Final`, they all have the right method.

My code like this, xxx for security reasons:

```
 val esc = new PreBuiltXPackTransportClient(settings)
      .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("xxx"), xxx))
      .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("xxx"), xxx))
```

Comment: Thanks for formating.

Answer (score 0):

You have two jars having the ObjectUtil class. JVM is deciding the class on runtime and generally picks the first one it gets.  I believe the other one would be coming from the `netty-all` jar. Can you check the dependency tree once?